# Issues with gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, datasource

I created a gridview with filter and everything fine but when I do gridview.databind(); nothing happen and with I change the page index nothing happen too.

I used scriptmanger,updatepanel and a little of javascript markup code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    onload="GridView1_Load" OnRowCreated="OnRowCreated" Width="614px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="Both" EmptyDataText="No Data To Show">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="areacode" HeaderText="areacode" 
            SortExpression="areacode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="areaename" HeaderText="areaename" 
            SortExpression="areaename" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="areaaname" HeaderText="areaaname" 
            SortExpression="areaaname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="areazipcode" HeaderText="areazipcode" 
            SortExpression="areazipcode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="districtcode" HeaderText="districtcode" 
            SortExpression="districtcode" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"/>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NetCareConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [areadata]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var gridViewCtlId = '<%=GridView1.ClientID%>';
    var gridViewCtl = null;
    var curSelRow = null;

    function onchange(evt) {
        PageMethods.getControlData(evt.target.id, document.getElementById(evt.target.id).value);
    }
    function getGridViewControl() {
        if (null == gridViewCtl) {
            gridViewCtl = document.getElementById(gridViewCtlId);
        }
    }

    function onGridViewRowSelected(rowIdx, isfiltered) {
        var selRow;
        //filter one
        if (rowIdx == '1' & isfiltered == 'True')
            selRow = null;
        else
            selRow = getSelectedRow(rowIdx);

        if (curSelRow != null) {
            curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        }

        if (selRow != null) {
            curSelRow = selRow;
            curSelRow.style.backgroundColor = '#8098B3';
        }




    }

    function getSelectedRow(rowIdx) {
        getGridViewControl();
        PageMethods.getRowSelected(rowIdx - 1);
        if (null != gridViewCtl) {
            return gridViewCtl.rows[rowIdx];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

code behind:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static string controlID, controlValue, selectedRowIndex;
    #region WebMethods
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void getControlData(string controlIDP, string controlValueP)
    {
        controlID = controlIDP;
        controlValue = controlValueP;
        _Default d = new _Default();
        d.textboxes_TextChanged();
    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void getRowSelected(string rowIndex)
    {
        selectedRowIndex = rowIndex;
    }
    #endregion    
    private void SetInitialRow(GridView inputGridView,SqlDataSource inputSqlDataSource)
    {
        if (inputGridView != null)
        {
            DataView dv = (DataView)inputSqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            object [] session=new object[2];
            session[0]=dv;
            session[1] = inputGridView;
            Session["GridView"] = session;
            TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[inputGridView.Columns.Count];
            DataTable dt = dv.Table.Clone();
            dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
            for (int row = 0; row < dv.Table.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow = dv.Table.Rows[row];
                dt.ImportRow(newRow);
            }
            inputGridView.DataSource = dt;
            inputGridView.DataBind();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                tb[i] = new TextBox();
                tb[i].Attributes.Add("id", i.ToString());
                if (!inputGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].HasControls())
                    inputGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].Controls.Add(tb[i]);
                else
                    inputGridView.Rows[0].Cells[i].Controls.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetInitialRow(GridView1, SqlDataSource1);  
    }
    public void textboxes_TextChanged()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlValue))
        {
            object[] session = (object[])Session["GridView"];
            DataView dv = (DataView)session[0];
            GridView1 = (GridView)session[1];
            String strexpr = string.Format("{0}={1}", dv.Table.Columns[int.Parse(controlID)], controlValue);
            DataRow[] rows = dv.Table.Select(strexpr);
            DataTable dt = dv.Table.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                dt.ImportRow(row);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "onGridViewRowSelected('" + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1).ToString() + "','" + true + "')");
        }
    }   
    protected void GridView1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints in your code on the DataBind() lines. When it hits the line, check the bound DataTable and make sure it contains information. The symptoms you are experiencing suggest that the filter is causing no data to be delivered to the Grid. If I am correct, it is not suprising you see nothing. I would be surprised if you have data just before bind.

The next step is to determine whether or not you have data initially.

One other option I can think of is you are doing an initial bind, but not rebinding after a change in values (resubmit, etc.). If this is the case, you need to set up a "cache" to hold the table and then filter as needed. Either that or make a return trip to the database.

Comment: i did wat u say about datatable and filter as needed

Comment: and i check data after the filtering and found in datatable one row with 5 column .the table in database have 5 column and the one row that wat i need to show

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which DataBind() is causing you problems.

When you execute:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
         SetInitialRow(GridView1, SqlDataSource1);       
}
```

You are passing the GridView1 by value so when you bind to it in the SetInitialValue function, so are binding to a copy, NOT the gridview on the WebForm. You could try passing the GridView1 by reference. The same would apply to SqlDataSource1.

**Edit**
See [ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more on the ref keyword in c#. If passing by reference, your code would look something like:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
         SetInitialRow(ref GridView1, ref SqlDataSource1);       
}
```

and

```
private void SetInitialRow(ref GridView inputGridView,ref SqlDataSource inputSqlDataSource)     
{
```

Comment: sry i write before but nothing added

Comment: how i did the call u r saying (by referance) plz write a example

Comment: sry i worked alot with c++ and there is pointer and in new languages like c# and java no pointer so i don't know pass by referance :D